# In C, why is the pointer returned by getenv automatically reclaimed?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, environment-variables, valgrind

I use the following code to test the pointer returned by `getenv`, if not free, testing will cause a memory leak.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void demo() {
    const char *home = getenv("HOME");
    printf("%s\n", home);
}

int main() {
    demo();
    return 0;
}
```

I use *Valgrind* to detect memory leaks:

```sh
$ gcc main.c -o main
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./main
```

The result is as follows:

```
==134679== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==134679== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==134679== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==134679== Command: ./demo
==134679== 
/home/aszswaz
==134679== 
==134679== HEAP SUMMARY:
==134679==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==134679==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==134679== 
==134679== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==134679== 
==134679== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==134679== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It shows that a piece of memory has been applied for and a piece of memory has been reclaimed. Why can the pointer obtained with `getenv` be automatically recycled?

If I add `free((void *)home)` to the code, will it affect the global environment variable?

Comment: Why do you think that the pointer obtained from getenv is actually pointing to a memory allocated on heap?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html explains everything about it.

Comment: don't confuse the pointer with what it points to. The pointer itself has automatic storage, the object it poitns to is a string that is not managed by you

Comment: That's going to be specific to how `getenv()` is specified, and how implementers choose to meet that specification.   In C++, any objects with static storage duration are destroyed after `main()` returns normally, in reverse order of their order of construction.  So it would certainly be feasible to implement `getenv()` to give the behaviour you describe in C++.   (Not making any comment on whether it is or isn't implemented in C++ - just that, feasibility in any language demonstrates that it is technically feasible in general).

Comment: You should never `free` a pointer obtained by `getenv` because it is not pointing to memory returned by `malloc`. The memory block in question is probably allocated and freed by `printf`, not by `getenv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html does not mention anything that `getenv()`'s return value is allocated on the heap. Hence, think of it like `argv`.

Although rarely and myself never seen this happen, in some implementations, `getenv()` may allocate memory on the heap and return a pointer to it. Therefore, its best to review your operating system's manual pages.

Only memory allocated on the heap must be `free()`d.

And, pointer to memory allocated on the heap is **usually** only returned when you call `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, `strdup()`, etc.

### Anyways:

If you do call `free()` on the pointer returned by `getenv()`, it is undefined behavior if your operating system did not return a pointer to memory on heap.

**And whoa, I almost didn't see this!:**
I think this is what is confusing you:

```
usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees
```

`printf()` may allocate on heap and free it before returning back.

### Edit:

Using gdb, we can find that:

```
#0  __GI___libc_malloc (1024) // and indeed it calls with 1024 bytes
#1  __GI__IO_file_doallocate ()
#2  __GI__IO_doallocbuf ()
#4  _IO_new_file_xsputn ()
#5  _IO_new_file_xsputn ()
#6  __GI__IO_puts
#7  demo ()
#8  main ()
```

`printf()` seems to be replaced by `puts()`, and `puts()` calls `malloc()` through a long function call chain.

But, it doesn't seem to call `free()`. I think it calls some other function that frees the memory. I'm still doing my research.

Comment: "getenv() allocate on heap and free() it before returning" and why would it do that? What kind of implementation of getenv do you have in mind?

Comment: I meant to say `getenv()` ***may***. Just a typo.

Comment: "... in some implementations, getenv() may allocate memory on the heap and return a pointer to it." Do you a reference for that? I don't think it's correct so I would like to see a reference. The whole description on `getenv` in the C standard indicates that the pointer is to a string which already is represent in memory.

Comment: @4386427 I think this is still possible, linux is a very large open source community, and there are many people who modify linux code to make linux run on their devices. We have no way of knowing how they will modify linux.

Comment: @aszswaz `getenv` is a standard C functions so the behavior must be consistent

Answer (score 0):

The environment is initialized on the initial process stack, just above the parameters `argc` and `argv` to `main()`.

Normally, as the environment life and parameters themselves is the whole program life, the common implementation consist in pushing the environment strings, the environment array, the main function parameter strings and the command line array in the stack, just before pushing the three variables (historically `main()` had a third parameter `environ`, that was passed also to main)  For legacy code reasons, this environment pointer is still passed to main.

Just try the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **environ)
{
    printf("argc = %d\n", argc);
    printf("args:");
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf(" [%s]", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\nEnvironment:\n");
    for (char **p = environ; *p; p++) {
        printf("  %s\n", *p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what `getenv()` returns is not statically allocated data, nor dynamically allocated data in the heap.  It is stored in the stack (almost all POSIX-like operating systems solve this problem in the same way) just above `main()` parameters (you can check it with a debugger, to see where are exactly located the strings, I have already done too)

So your problem is not related to `getenv()`, which doesn't use `malloc()` to return dynamically allocated strings to you.
You'll need to look elsewhere for that memory Valgrind identifies as dynamic (It doesn't show any problem with it)

Think that valgrind identifies the memory you have allocated with `malloc()` (or any of its friends) and not `free()`d, and the report says at `exit()` there's no memory allocated.  So `getenv()` doesn't allocate memory to give you the environment contents.

If you read on how the kernel initializes a process memory's initial stack, you will find very interesting things (listed from most deep in the stack to the top of it):

- There's some fixed machine code to properly return from kernel mode when there's a pending interrupt (interrupts are executed only when the kernel switches from kernel mode to user mode because they have to execute the handler code in user mode, and never in kernel mode, for obvious reasons)
- There's a legacy structure to save command line parameters and to allow the kernel to access command parameters for ps(1) command to work.  This is no longer true, as it represents a security hole to put kernel info in user space, but the structure is still there, for legacy code to use.  The parameters for a command are now in kernel space, and can only be modified by a special system call.
- There are all the strings associated to the received environment of the process.
- The array of pointer to the environment strings is also stored in the stack.  This includes a final `NULL` pointer to be able to identify the end of the array.
- All the strings of the command line parameters are also stored there.
- The array of pointers (including the last `NULL` pointer, which is not counted in `argc`) of the command line parameters.
- The parameter `environ` with a pointer to the array of environment strings.
- The parameter `argv` with a pointer to the array of command line parameters.
- The parameter `argc` with the number of command line parameters (this includes the program name, but excludes the last `NULL` pointer)